# Join multiple Tables based on multiple criteria over one field

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I need find the most efficient way to join one table, to other three, using as criteria the values on theirs [Id_Orig] fields

Consider Table1 as the one with our universe of data, having the fields Below:

```
Select Id_Orig, F1, F2 From Table1
```

The field [Id_Orig] can have only three values: 'DO', 'CC' and 'DP'. I need to join other three tables with ***Table1***, based on those values as shown below:

- **Table1** left join **Table_DO** : only for those records that have both [Id_Orig] = 'DO'
- **Table1** left join **Table_CC** : only for those records that have both [Id_Orig] = 'CC'
- **Table1** left join **Table_DP** : only for those records that have both [Id_Orig] = 'DP'

Suppose that Table1 has 1000 records, these must remain unchanged. The idea is only to add the fields from the other respective linked tables, as shown below:

```
Table1.Id_Orig, Table1.F1, Table1.F2, Table_DO.*, Table_CC.*, Table_DP.*
```

Can anyone tell me, please, how is the best way to achieve that, and if that could be done on the 'ON' Clause after the Left Join?

Thanks in advance.
Leopoldo Fernandes
Portugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, tdo.*, tcc.*, tdp*  
FROM Table1 AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_DO AS tdo ON t1.[Id_Orig] = tdo.[Id_Orig] AND t1.[Id_Orig] = 'DO' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_CC AS tcc ON t1.[Id_Orig] = tcc.[Id_Orig] AND t1.[Id_Orig] = 'CC' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_DP AS tdp ON t1.[Id_Orig] = tdp.[Id_Orig] AND t1.[Id_Orig] = 'DP'
```

For example, when you JOIN to `Table_DO`, you said you want when both tables have `[Id_Orig]` = 'DO' ... since the JOIN condition is the values are equal, you only need to specify one column (I choose Table1).

Comment: Hi @Bjorg P, Suppose, in this context, I would link [Table1] only to [Table_CC], which has only 500 records; the result would be the 1,000 records, of which 500 with data only for 'CC', and the remaining 500 would be null?
Thank's in advance

Comment: That is what should be shown since these are LEFT OUTER JOINs and not INNER JOINs.